# ES6: Conditional use of spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to write an expression which takes the value of the `query` parameter and generates a new object which contains everything in `query` and the default `$sort` value, but only if `$sort` is not already present.

I feel like I should use the the spread operator `...` to do this, but don't know how I could use it in this instance.

The below code does not work as it always returns `{$sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}`
Ideally it should print out what's in the comments next to the `console.log` statements:

```
'use strict'
const funcUnderTest = (query) => ({
  query: /^sort/.test(query) ? query : {$sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}
})

console.log(funcUnderTest(null)) // Should be { query: {$sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({}))) // Should be { query: {$sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({forCandidate: 123}))) // Should be { query: {forCandidate: 123, $sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({$sort: {name:1}}))) // Should be { query: {$sort: {name: 1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({forCandidate: 123, $sort: {name:1}}))) // Should be { forCandidate: 123, query: {$sort: {name: 1}}}
```

Comment: regex works on strings but seem to be putting objects into the funcUnderTest function which probably explains why it always fails.

Comment: I have no idea why you think the spread operator would help here?

Comment: Should `forCandidate` be always part of the query, always be outside, or is it really variable depending on whether there's a sort key?

Comment: `forCandidate` is only part of the query if it's used to narrow down a search, to get results targeting only one specific candidate

Comment: Thanks @jollarvia, should have mentioned that I was getting `is not a function` errors in the console

Comment: @Bergi Also the reason why I thought the spread operator could help is because I thought I could do something like `const c = {
  ...a,
  ...b,
}`

Comment: `...` isn't (and can't be) an operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` for this.

I'm going to assume your last example output is a mistake (should be `{ query: {$sort: {name: 1}, forCandidate: 123}}`) because it's inconsistent with your other expected outputs.

```js
'use strict'
const funcUnderTest = (query) => ({
  query: Object.assign({$sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}, query || {})
})

console.log(funcUnderTest(null)) // Should be { query: {$sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({}))) // Should be { query: {$sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({forCandidate: 123}))) // Should be { query: {forCandidate: 123, $sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({$sort: {name:1}}))) // Should be { query: {$sort: {name: 1}}}
console.log(funcUnderTest(({forCandidate: 123, $sort: {name:1}}))) // Should be { forCandidate: 123, query: {$sort: {name: 1}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JLRishe 's answer, and understanding that Object.assign is the same as using spread syntax except that since it's non-mutative there is no need for the `{}` after the `||`, here is the version with spread syntax.

```js
'use strict'

const funcUnderTest = (query) => ({
  query:
    {
      $sort: {priority: -1, createdAt: -1},
      ...query
    }
})

console.log(funcUnderTest(null))
console.log(funcUnderTest(({})))
console.log(funcUnderTest(({forCandidate: 123})))
console.log(funcUnderTest(({$sort: {name:1}})))
console.log(funcUnderTest(({forCandidate: 123, $sort: {name:1}})))
```

Comment: `{...{…}, …}` makes no sense. Just write `{…, …}` directly.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, and I even just removed the spread operator from the object literal, as there's no point spreading an object literal.